# Add text to a pseudo element on the second click of the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very basic function that shows the `:after` of a div `onclick` by adding a class to it.

All I want to achieve is that, from the second click on, the `:after` would change from "THIS" to "AND THIS"

Any hint?
Thanks!

```js
$(document).on("click","#click",function(){$("#logo").addClass("open")});
```

```css
#click{cursor:pointer}
#logo.open:after{content:" THIS"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click">CLICK HERE</div><br>
<div id="logo">SHOT</div>
```

Comment: You can't manipulate the content of a pseudo element directly, but you can have the content reference a data attribute instead, then manipulate that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if the element has `.open`, and if so, add a new class that overwrites the `::after` content

```js
var $logo = $('#logo');
$(document).on("click","#click",function(){
  if ($logo.hasClass('open')) {
    $logo.addClass('and');
  } else {
    $logo.addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
#click{cursor:pointer}
#logo.open::after{content:" THIS"}
#logo.and::after{content:" AND THIS"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click">CLICK HERE</div><br>
<div id="logo">SHOT</div>
```